# Friend function can no longer access private data members of class after class is encapsulated in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

I have a class called Circle that I encapsulated inside a namespace.

```
namespace my_name_space {
    class Circle;
}

class my_name_space::Circle {
private:
    double radius;
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Circle &c);
};
```

Here is the function in the implementation file:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Circle &c)
{
    os << "Radius: " << c.radius;

    return os;
}
```

Before encapsulating the class within the namespace, everything was working fine. Now the friend function can no longer access the private data members. I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare `operator <<` as the [friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of `Circle`, it'll become the member of the innermost enclosing namespace of `Circle`. That means when you put `Circle` into namespace `my_name_space`, `operator <<` becomes the member of namespace `my_name_space` too. The definiton of `operator<<` doesn't match that, it defines `operator<<` at globle scope.

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X

You can move the definition of `operator<<` into namespace `my_name_space`:

```
namespace my_name_space {
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Circle &c) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or if you still want to keep `operator<<` at global scope:

```
// delcaration
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const my_name_space::Circle &c);
class my_name_space::Circle {
    ...
    friend std::ostream& ::operator << (std::ostream &os, const Circle &c);
    //                   ~~
};
// definition
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const my_name_space::Circle &c) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: what if i have a using declaration at the top of the implementation file as, `using my_namespace` would the `operator` need to still be qualified?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm Yes. `using namespace my_name_space;` won't make declarations after it become members of `my_name_space`.

Comment: `using` declaration explains why OP's code compiled with `const Circle &c` being unqualified. It was a puzzle for me.

Comment: Your first suggestion gives a compiler warning, while the second one doesn't.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I'm using clang and it doesn't omit any warning. I'm not sure which one is correct; anyway I changed the style which won't cause doubt.